# Can Acrobat Pro edit locked text layers in PDF?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-acrobat

I'm new to freelancing, and I want to send the final work to client in PDF.
I want the client to be able to edit text layers only, I *locked* all layers in the AI file.

and I'm choosing to save as PDF with un-checking preserve illustrator editing capabilities.

**Is this the right way to deliver this PDF to the client?**

**Can he edit text this way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locking *any* layer in Illustrator (or Photoshop, or InDesign) has no effect in PDFs.

Layer locking is a function of the *originating* application and has no bearing on output.

You're free to try this yourself. You should be able to open your PDF and edit the text in Acrobat. But then, you'll also be able to use the Object Touch Up Tool to edit anything else as well.

It's difficult to limit editing but allow some. Generally, it's best to either supply a file to be edited, or supply a file which is *not* to be edited. But with Illustrator it's pretty impossible to supply an uneditable file. You can make editing some things much more difficult, but you can't prevent editing overall in a vector file, even as a PDF.